# Loading Variable from URL, only works for numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My URL is example.com/load_item.html?item=QB123

Where QB123 is a random assortment of letters & numbers we'll call item_code.

I need to parse the URL grab the item_code and input it into a form on the page.

Here's what I have:

```html
<div class="col_full">
<label for="item_code">Item Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="item_code1" name="item_code" class="form-control"  required/>
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('item_code1').value=+window.location.search.substr(6) ; 
</script>
```

It works if the item_code is all numbers (e.g., 12345). However when there are letters included the form value is submitted as NaN.  Any ideas

Comment: You are coercing the value to a number with the "+". If it's all numbers, great. But letters cause NaN

Comment: Any reason why you don't use an URL query string parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the plus sign should be at the left of the equal sign in order to concatenate the strings:

```
document.getElementById('item_code1').value += window.location.search.substr(6) ;
```

Otherwise you are treating `window.location.search.substr(6)` as a number.

Comment: Lol, thank you.  Completely overlooked that. It was driving me nuts.

Comment: Don't forget to check that check mark if he answered your question so @taxicala gets credit, and so that people dont keep trying to answer the post as if it is unanswered

Answer (score 2):

This will give you an object with your query parameters:

```
 var obj = {};
 location.search.replace('?','').split('&').forEach(
    function(item){
      arr = item.split('='); 
      obj[arr[0]] = arr[1]; 
    }
 );
```

So for your example, if you console.log the obj variable you will get:

```
 Object {item: "QB123"}
```